# theme for python eric ide

Tags: python, ide, styles, eric-ide

I want to change my background IDE in eric but when I do this in preferences>editor>style nothing change in background color, just font styles changed.

Is there any solution for this? cause white color make a huge damage in editor when working lots of hours

Comment: If you're on windows you can use the magnifier to invert the screen.

Comment: FYI, I have been working with white (or light grey) backgrounds for almost 30 years now, without any "damage". On the contrary, the light background causes a narrower pupil, with sharper vision and less fatigue as a result (which may not be noticeable if you are young and with a good eyesight)

Comment: If you're on GNU/Linux, you can install `xcalib` and run `xcalib -invert -alter` to invert all your screen.  It's quite efficient.  I mapped the Scroll Lock key (mostly unused nowadays) to this command (using `xbindkeys`), and I regularly hit that key, according to my mood.
White background for 35 years, no damage, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version:
[ **Settings** > **preferences** > *Editor* > *Style* ] ... is only for unrecognised languages.
[ **Settings** > **Preferences** > *Editor* > *Highlighters* > *Styles* ] ... is for each separate recognized language.

Longer version:
Changing the background using [ **Settings** > **Preferences** > *Editor* > *Style* ] works fine. ... Well kinda.

1. This particular preference section is only for setting the style on files that are seen by the eric-ide as "*No language*" files.
2. This has no effect on the empty editing-area display (*ie: when there are no files open*).
3. The change 'might' not show up immediately. In my case I had to re-click on the "*No language*" option ([ **RMC/file-content-menu** > *languages* > No language ]) to get the background colour change to show up as intended.

To change the background for a, by the eric-ide, known language. You have to go to [ **Settings** > **Preferences** > *Editor* > *Highlighters* > *Styles* ], and than select the languages you like to make the changes for.

-- Checked against: eric6 (18.06)
-- No general-theme support: https://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/issues/issue248

Answer (score 1):

You can change the complete look of the IDE, but it's split between four different settings menus:

1. In **Settings** > **Preferences** > **Editor** > **Highlighters** > **Styles** click "Import styles" near the bottom, and choose one of the predefined themes.
2. Now you can't see your text cursor, because it's still black. Go to **Settings** > **Preferences** > **Editor** > **Styles**, scroll down to "Caret", and change the "Foreground" color to white. In the same menu, you can also change the color of the margins.
3. The surrounding panels are still white. Go to **Settings** > **Preferences** > **Interface** > **Interface** and in "Style Sheet" choose one of the predefined styles.
4. Now you can't see the icons in the top bar, because they are black on a dark background. Go to **Settings** > **Icons** and change "Default icons" to "Breeze (dark)"

Works for eric7.