# Eric IDE dark theme

Tags: themes, eric-ide

I started using Eric IDE but cannot find a way to set a dark theme. I was using just Geany text editor before and I had a dark theme, now I'm used to it. I'd like the IDE debugging features but the white background really hurts my eyes.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. The site is for people with coding problems where they show their code and people help them with specific challenges. Please read the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I upvoted it, because its a question about a programming tool and its configuration for efficient coding. For me that is a relevant coding aspect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [theme for python eric ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788747/theme-for-python-eric-ide)

Answer (score 0):

(*Figure I might gain some useful points ... ergo (adjusted answer from [theme-for-python-eric-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50889144/3065144) question*)

To change the background for a, by the eric-ide, known language. You have to go to [ **Settings** > **Preferences** > *Highlighters* > *Styles* ], and than select the languages you like to make the changes for.

[ **Settings** > **preferences** > *Editor* > *Style* ] ... is only for unrecognised languages.
[ **Settings** > **Preferences** > *Highlighters* > *Styles* ] ... is for each separate recognized language.

-- Checked against: eric6 (18.06)
-- No general-theme support: https://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/issues/issue248

Comment: They have changed the website, so the link to Eric issues above does not work any more. The updated link is now https://www.mail-archive.com/eric@riverbankcomputing.com/msg03970.html. This page, btw, is the second most useful resource for Eric questions after the "Technical Document" on the Eric website.

Comment: Actual link is now https://tracker.die-offenbachs.homelinux.org/issues/issue248